# Why does grep loop getdents system call?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, grep, linux-kernel

I am running a recursive grep command against a webspace on a Linux Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS server in order to find all files with the specific phrase. The command seems to be hanging and not doing anything. I ran a strace on the process and it seems to be stuck on getdent system call.

The command looks like this:

`grep -r needle /var/www/haystack`

When I run a strace on the process, I get these results:

```
strace -p 2066
strace: Process 2066 attached
getdents(4, /* 585 entries */, 32768)   = 32760
getdents(4, /* 585 entries */, 32768)   = 32760
getdents(4, /* 585 entries */, 32768)   = 32760
getdents(4, /* 585 entries */, 32768)   = 32760
getdents(4, /* 585 entries */, 32768)   = 32760
getdents(4, /* 585 entries */, 32768)   = 32760
getdents(4, /* 585 entries */, 32768)   = 32760
getdents(4, /* 585 entries */, 32768)   = 32760
getdents(4, /* 585 entries */, 32768)   = 32760
getdents(4, /* 585 entries */, 32768)   = 32760
getdents(4, /* 585 entries */, 32768)   = 32760
getdents(4, /* 585 entries */, 32768)   = 32760
getdents(4, /* 585 entries */, 32768)   = 32760
getdents(4, /* 585 entries */, 32768)   = 32760
getdents(4, /* 585 entries */, 32768)   = 32760
getdents(4, /* 585 entries */, 32768)   = 32760
getdents(4, /* 585 entries */, 32768)   = 32760
getdents(4, /* 585 entries */, 32768)   = 32760
getdents(4, /* 585 entries */, 32768)   = 32760
getdents(4, /* 585 entries */, 32768)   = 32760
getdents(4, /* 585 entries */, 32768)   = 32760
getdents(4, /* 585 entries */, 32768)   = 32760
getdents(4, /* 585 entries */, 32768)   = 32760
getdents(4, /* 585 entries */, 32768)   = 32760
getdents(4, /* 585 entries */, 32768)   = 32760
getdents(4, /* 585 entries */, 32768)   = 32760
getdents(4
```

Why is grep just looping through getdents and not progressing? Is there a way to diagnose or remedy this issue without interrupting the command?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Does one of your directories have a very large number of files?

Comment: You can see what file descriptor 4 is by inspecting `/proc/<PID>/fd`.

Comment: @jordanm I was able to use your info to determine that it is getting stuck listing a concrete5 tmp directory. Sounds like it's likely too large for the buffer?

Comment: Linux filesystems in general perform terribly with large numbers of files in a single directory. It's even worse with tools like `ls` which read the entire directory and then sort before displaying.